# How to implement a google-login for any google APIs in a Django wep-app?

Tags: django, google-api, google-signin

I'm currently developing a Django web app that will allow users to sign-in with their google account and get access to their Google Calendar and Google Drive data.

I already succeeded in doing so on another project in a front-end context using an Angular library called ng-gapi (GoogleAuthService) but I can't seem to find an equivalent for Django! All I was able to do for the moment is to implement a simple google login, but can't communicate with the different google APIs.

I have tried to use a module called django-allauth but it only logs-in the user via google but without providing any useful information (like authorization tokens etc...) needed to grant the web app to communicate with the user's google data.

```html
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
{% load static %}
<html>

    <body>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome {{ user.username }}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout/">Log out</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="http://localhost:8000/show/">My Gigs</a>
        <p>You're logged in with {{ user.get_provider }} as {{ user }}.</p>
        <img style="max-width: 80px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px" src="{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}" />
        <p>UID: {{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.uid }}</p>      
        <p>Date Joined: {{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.date_joined}}</p>
        <p>Last Login: {{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.last_login}}</p>   
        <p>{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data.name }}</p> 

        {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Log in</a>
        {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to log-in this way, I get the google sign-in page which works well, but I don't have the second window which would have to be the one concerning the user granting my web-app to have access to his Google Calendar and Google Drive data (even though I have already configured it in my google developer console).

I would be immensely grateful if you could help me, I know that it looks as if this question has been answered multiple times but I have read hundreds of posts on the subject and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Django social auth library](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django)

An example of the implementation is [here](https://medium.com/trabe/oauth-authentication-in-django-with-social-auth-c67a002479c1)

You should enable access to google calendar and disk API from **GOOGLE API CONSOLE**